# How to search for higher values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have tables:

```
City:
id | name
1  | New York
2  | Amsterdam
3  | Paris
4  | London


Trip:
id | name 
1  | aaaa // New York --> Paris --> London
2  | bbbb // London --> Paris --> Amsterdam
3  | cccc // London --> New York --> Amsterdam --> Paris
4  | dddd // Paris --> London
5  | eeee // Amsterdam --> London 

TripDetails:
id | tripId | cityId| order
1  | 1      |  1    | 1
2  | 1      |  3    | 2
3  | 1      |  4    | 3
4  | 2      |  4    | 1
5  | 2      |  3    | 2
6  | 2      |  2    | 3
7  | 3      |  4    | 1
8  | 3      |  1    | 2
9  | 3      |  2    | 3
10 | 3      |  3    | 4
11 | 4      |  3    | 1
12 | 4      |  4    | 2
13 | 5      |  2    | 1
14 | 5      |  4    | 2
```

Now i would like find cities by city using trips.

For example if i get Amsterdam then i would like receive Paris (Trip ID = 3) and London (Trip ID = 5). NOT New York because in Trip 3 New York is before Amsterdam.

Other example:

If i get New York then i should receive all cities - Paris (Trip 1), London (Trip 1) and Amsterdam (Trip 3).

If i get Paris then i should receive only London and Amsterdam.

So i have for Paris (ID: 3):

```
SELECT * FROM "City" 
LEFT JOIN "TripDetails" ON City.id = TripDetails.cityId 
WHERE TripDetails.cityId = 3
AND ????
```

How can i do it?

I can change the whole structure of the database if necessary. I use PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. This example is for New York (city id = 1) :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/911ec5/7)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT distinct city.name
FROM tripDetails td1
INNER JOIN tripDetails td2 ON td1.tripId = td2.tripId AND
                              td2.order > td1.order
INNER JOIN city ON td2.cityId = city.id
INNER JOIN trip ON td2.tripId = trip.id
WHERE td1.cityID = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/911ec5/7/0)**:

```
|      NAME |
|-----------|
|     Paris |
|    London |
| Amsterdam |
```